# facebook share no work on facebook ios app

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm tryng to make a share button like youtube, where you can chose if you want to share the content into a page that you own.

Here my js code to open share window:

```
function share(url){
    myWindow = window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+url, '',     
    'width=700,height=350');
    myWindow.focus();
}
```

Then I add to the shared content the OG metas:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://my-url.com/content">
<meta property="og:title" content="content title">
<meta property="og:description" content="description title">
<meta property="og:type" content="video.other">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://my_url.com/image.jpg">
<meta property="og:video" content="http://my-url.com/content">
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="http://my-url.com/content">
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash">
<meta property="og:video:width" content="400">
<meta property="og:video:height" content="300">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="site name">
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="APPID">
<meta property="fb:admins" content="admin_id">
```

It works correctly, but when I share something by this way and I try to open it by the Facebook iPhone APP from my wall or from a friends wall, it doesn't works.

Thanks in advance.